# Laurent expansion of $f(z)=\frac{z}{z^2+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

The exercise:
Find the laurent expansion of $f(z)=\frac{z}{z^2+1}$ in $K_{1,2}(-i)$.

My thoughts:
$K_{1,2}(-i)$ denotes the annulus. 1 and 2 the radiuses.
First thing I did is decompose in partial fractions. I.e. 
$f(z)=\frac{z}{z^2+1}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{z+i}+\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{z-i}$
Usually I rewrite $K_{1,2}(-i)$ as $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:0<|z+i|<\sqrt3 = |\sqrt2 +i|\}$. And then I rewrite the denominator in terms of $|z+i|$ like this:
$\frac{1/2}{z-i}=\frac{1/2}{(z+i)-(2i)}=\ldots$ but this time it somehow doesn't work. Especially with $\frac{1/2}{z+i}$. I think I'am missing something crucial.